# Remove rows based on columns values

Tags: r, na

There are four variables in “mydata”, and I need to remove the rows that have NA in either x1 OR x2 (but not other variables). So

What I have

```
mydata <- data.frame(y=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4), x1=c(1,NA,1,2,4,5,1, NA ,2,5,2,6,2,6,NA,2,6,NA), x2=c(1,NA,1,NA,1,1,8,2,2,2,4,1,NA,1,4,2,7,NA), x3=c(1,4,1,NA,1,1,8,2,2,NA,4,1,1,1,NA,2,7,2))
```

What I need

```
    y   x1  x2  x3
1   1   1   1   1
3   1   1   1   1
5   1   4   1   1
6   2   5   1   1
7   2   1   8   8
9   2   2   2   2
10  3   5   2   NA
11  3   2   4   4
12  3   6   1   1
14  4   6   1   1
16  4   2   2   2
17  4   6   7   7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
  mydata[!rowSums(is.na(mydata[,c('x1', 'x2')])),]
  #   y x1 x2 x3
  #1  1  1  1  1
  #3  1  1  1  1
  #5  1  4  1  1
  #6  2  5  1  1
  #7  2  1  8  8
  #9  2  2  2  2
  #10 3  5  2 NA
  #11 3  2  4  4
  #12 3  6  1  1
  #14 4  6  1  1
  #16 4  2  2  2
  #17 4  6  7  7
```

Or

```
  mydata[!with(mydata, is.na(x1)|is.na(x2)),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be

```
mydata[is.na(mydata$x1)==FALSE & is.na(mydata$x2) == FALSE, ]
#   y x1 x2 x3
#1  1  1  1  1
#3  1  1  1  1
#5  1  4  1  1
#6  2  5  1  1
#7  2  1  8  8
#9  2  2  2  2
#10 3  5  2 NA
#11 3  2  4  4
#12 3  6  1  1
#14 4  6  1  1
#16 4  2  2  2
#17 4  6  7  7
```

Behind the scenes: `is.na` just checks logical status, for example

```
is.na(mydata$x1)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[12] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

is.na(mydata$x2)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[12] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

So putting them together

```
is.na(mydata$x1) == FALSE & is.na(mydata$x2) == FALSE
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#[12]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Then `[ *, ]` is going to keep the 12 rows where `is.na(mydata$x1) == FALSE & is.na(mydata$x2) == FALSE` is `TRUE`.  The second suggestion in akrun's answer uses the same logic, but leverages the not operator `!`, which is another good way to approach the problem.